# SSAS MDX query as Azure Data Factory source in Linked Service

Tags: ssas, mdx, azure-data-factory

This question might not be well researched but I need to find out proper way to implement this solution before starting design.

Question is, Can we consume SSAS MDX query as datasource in Azure Data Factory Linked Service source?

Comment: Here I uploaded a nice workaround, a powershell script that can query mdx and gets its csv representation. Then you can do whatever you need with it. I'm running it from Azure Automation so thats why the first line gets the credentials like that. https://gist.github.com/Gorgoras/051dede7d44a47f3d69c1756797ce5e4

Answer (score 3):

Data factory cannot query SSAS with MDX or DAX, but maybe you can query the source of the SSAS, in a traditional BI architecture it would be a Data Warehouse or a SQL server. This is because SSAS models are meant to be consumed by reporting tools (Power BI, reporting services, etc) and not data integration tools, which serve very different processes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The supported list of connectors for the Copy activity available as at today is available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats

It looks like SSAS MDX queries are not included at this point.

ADF v2 supports the running of SSIS packages within ADF pipelines so it *may* be possible via that route (untested).